# Вывод массива - php

Tags: php, opencart

Есть форма:

```
<form>
    <div class="block">
        <input type="text" name="name[0]">
        <input type="text" name="phone[0]">
        <input type="text" name="email[0]">
    </div>

    <div class="block">
        <input type="text" name="name[1]">
        <input type="text" name="phone[1]">
        <input type="text" name="email[1]">
    </div>
</form>
```

Т.е. полей может быть N-е количество, но всегда по 3 и в атрибуте `name` всегда +1 в каждом блоке.

Но проблема в том что когда собираю массив:

```
if (isset($this->request->post['name'])) {
    $name = $this->request->post['name'];
} elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
    $name = $module_info['name'];
} else {
    $name = '';
}
if (isset($this->request->post['phone'])) {
    $phone = $this->request->post['phone'];
} elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
    $phone = $module_info['phone'];
} else {
    $phone = '';
}
if (isset($this->request->post['email'])) {
    $email = $this->request->post['email'];
} elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
    $email = $module_info['email'];
} else {
    $email = '';
}
$data['get_all'][] = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'phone' => $phone,
    'email' => $email,
);
```

То не получается отобразить поля формы в том порядке в котором они были. Т.е. по три в блоке. 
Получается так:

```
<form>
    <div class="block">
        <input type="text" name="name[0]">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <input type="text" name="name[1]">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <input type="text" name="phone[0]">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <input type="text" name="phone[1]">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <input type="text" name="email[0]">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <input type="text" name="email[1]">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: не совсем понятно, как вы этим набором ифов что-то выводите. Разбейте на группы array_chunk($arr, 3); и выводите

Comment: @splash58 array_chunk не совсем то что нужно. он и так на группы разбит, но не на те что нужно. т.е. идет по порядку (name[0], name[1], phone[0]), а нужно что-бы чередовалось (name[0], phone[0], email[0]).

Comment: вы же собираете во анутренние массивы [] = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'phone' => $phone,
    'email' => $email,
);  разбивайте внешний и выводите

Comment: именуйте не 3 массива а один `result[0][phone], result[0][name]`  и собирать не надо ничего.

Comment: @teran точно) спасибо!